# Backbone.js view uses instance of self to render children. Is that okay?

Tags: backbone.js, view, architecture

I'm building a node tree where all of the nodes can have child nodes and those child nodes can have grandchildren and so on and so forth ...

I can get away with this using just a single view that will in turn render any children listed in it's model. What I have now looks like this:

```
define(["backbone", "text!templates/node-tree/node.html"], function(Backbone, NodeTmpl) {

    var NodeView;

    return NodeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        className: "node",
        template: _.template(NodeTmpl),
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            if (this.model.get("children")) {
                this.renderChildren();
            }
        },
        renderChildren: function() {
            var container = this.el.querySelector(".child-nodes");
            for (var i = 0; i < this.model.get("children").length; i++) {
                var child = this.model.get("children")[i];
                var view = new NodeView({model: child});
                container.appendChild(view.el);
            }
            return this;
        }
    });

});
```

Now, is this OK? I mean I see it working, but am I setting my self up for some nasty surprises down the road? The other option is to have 2 identical view classes (NodeA, NodeB) and have them use each other for rendering the children respectively. However, this is obviously not very DRY and if I don't need to go that route I would rather not.

Comment: Sure. Way better than having two identical views. Just make sure circular dependencies can't occur, whatever approach you take.

Comment: You might want to keep track of the children inside `NodeView` so that you can override `remove` and properly clean everything up.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course. This was a reduced sample of my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to do that. This is very similar to Marionette's CompositeView. Marionette's composite's default behavior (if the itemView/childView property isn't defined) is to use the composite view itself as the children view.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md

I personally have used this structure myself. I had a hierarchical data object and they needed to be rendered the children view the same as the container view (with some css tweaks).